# Remove Commas from Large CSV (1GB)

Tags: python, matlab, csv

I have a large CSV file (1GB) that I would like to remove commas from.  The data are all positive integers.  Methods I have tried include dlmwrite with a space as the delimiter, but the output is then output in decimal format.  I have also tried to use the fprintf command, but then I lose the shape of the matrix (i.e. all data appear in one line or column).

Thus,

Is there a simple way to read in from a CSV (input.txt):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

and then output to a text file (output.txt) in the form:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: `tr -d, < FILE`?

Comment: Matlab is what I have the most experience with, but I'm delving into python as well.  My suspicion is that python would be better suited for this, but I thought I'd save some time using something I already know.  However, it's been more challenging than I expected, so I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: As hroptatyr suggested, `tr` is probably the best tool for the job, but instead of removing the commas, you might rather want to replace them with a space: `tr ',' ' '`.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to put this into some kind of analyzable form, then you should be using pandas which can read in almost any kind of text file containing data. Since this looks like a simple case you might even be able to just call `pandas.read_csv('input.txt')` and get back a `DataFrame`. Why do you want to write such a huge file *back to text*? That's not really useful at all...

Comment: Also, [MATLAB is absolutely terrible at reading text files](http://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 11):

In Python, if the format is really that simple (and there already is a space after each comma):

```
with open("infile.csv") as infile, open("outfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.replace(",", ""))
```

If you can't be sure about whitespace:

```
import re
with open("infile.csv") as infile, open("outfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(re.sub(r"\s*,\s*", " ", line))
```

Comment: While this is correct, it will be *extremely* slow for a 1GB text file.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to use sed, a command line program that replaces strings.

This application is available on linux and via a cygwin install also in windows.

Using

```
sed -i 's/,/ /g' filename
```

all the commas in the file are replaced by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can read line by line using fgetl from a file descriptor like this:

```
fid=fopen('file.csv');
if (fid==-1)
    return
end
sl=fgetl(fid);        
while (~feof(fid))
    sl=fgetl(fid);  
    icol=find(sl==',');
end  

fclose(fid);
```

In sl you can replace the , by spaces and write again to disk

Answer (score 0):

python has a `csv` module for CSV file i/o.

```
import csv
with open("input.txt") as infile:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for line in csv.reader(infile):
            outfile.write(' '.join(line)+'\n')
```

Similarly matlab has a csvread function

```
M = csvread('input.txt');
dlmwrite('output.txt', M, 'delimiter', ' ', 'precision', '%ld');
```

but this code has issues. First you read the file in a single big chunk, and not line for line: you can run out of memory. Second `csvread` always returns a `double` array, so precision may be lost when reading big integers. Finally if `input.txt` has a variable number of columns, matrix `M` is zero filled.

python solution strongly recommended!